# how to upload file in headless mode without button tag

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework, headless

Is there any way to upload a file using rebot framework without tag and with the headless mode activated. I tried to use AutoIt and sikuliLibrary but they are not working .

best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `input` element,  you can use `Choose File` keyword :

```
Choose File    id=input_id    C://document/file.txt
```

Check the documentation : https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file with Selenium by sending the file you want to upload to a special file.
This will work regardless to the headless or regular Selenium mode.
With Python language syntax it will be:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("the_full_path_to_your_file")
```

With other languages it will be similar, just with some syntax changes.